# Loading an object inside an object in a Django template

Tags: python, django

So I have an object that has a foreign key of another object. Whenever I load that object into a template and access said object, I get an error.

```
<td><a href="{% url 'agente' 'Mark' %}" target="_blank">{{ ticket.get_agente }}</a></td>
```

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Agente'
Exception Location:     /dashound/demoModule/models.py, line 113, in get_agente
```

I even tried adding a get_id after getting the object but displays the same error. Seems like the fact that it's an object inside an object confuses Django.

Edit: Didn't specify, the error is in `ticket.get_agente` getting the Agente object out of the Ticket object.

Comment: Can you show your urls file? The error saying that router expect object ID.

Comment: The error is in get_agente (says it in the message) the URL works fine if get_agente is removed.

Comment: Ok, then you need to show this method code. Maybe it have the `reverse` function call?

Comment: Solved it before editing the question. The method was returning INT so it returned an object to an int() conversion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was that the method of the model `get_agente()` returned the Agente object to a int conversion `return int(self.agente)`. Fixed it changing it to `str()`. Thanks to @Charnel for making me see it!